# Kotlin - Type mismatch: Required: String, Found: () -> String

Tags: string, kotlin, type-mismatch

In Kotlin I declared a `List<String>` like this:

```
private val items = listOf<String> {
        "String1",
        "String2",
        "String3"
    }
```

the compiler is giving me this error:

> Type Mismatch.
>
> Required: String
>
> Found: () -> String

What does it mean? How do I fix it?

P.S. Pretty new to Kotlin so bear with me for asking something obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You passed the argument enclosed in `{}` which introduced a function literal (lambda) which is why the compiler finds a function type

> Found: () -> String

Instead just use parentheses like this:

```
listOf("String1", "String2")
```

Some information:

Kotlin allows you to pass functions after the `()` when passed as **the last** argument. The parentheses can be left away if the function is **the only** argument as in your example. Therefore the code is valid but simply does not match the function parameter type.

Comment: Thank you for the great and detailed answer. As I wrote in the question, I'm a begginner in Kotlin and this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private val items = listOf("String1", "String2", "String3")
```

Comment: Yeah this works, Thanks. Please, argument on the answer and explain what I did wrong.

Comment: Does not explain the error which means { } is a function literal () -> declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem trying to add headers to retrofit in Kotlin.

**Java Code was:**

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json",
    "userName: blah@test.com"
})
```

It turns out the solution was not listOf or arrayOf, but to just remove the {}

**Kotlin Solution:**

```
@Headers("Accept: application/json",
    "userName: blah@test.com"
)
```

Reference: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2518